# Non-continuous range in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I need to select all rows except one from OpenCV matrix. What I came up with is to select rows from two ranges (from 0 to i and from i + 1 to matrix.rows) and concatenate them to a new matrix.

But this solution seems very dirty: concatenation copies the data to a new matrix, which I don't need. Moreover, when i = 0 or matrix.rows, an error occurs during concatenation, because one of the submatrices becomes empty, so this case should be handled separately. All this issues cause too much pain, and what I need is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Not enough thought to make an answer. But if you only need this for limited purposes (i.e. not the whole ndarray interface), it seems like you could make a class that takes the pair/set of non-continuous ranges you need in init and then on access modifies the input coordinates to return from the original ndarray?

Comment: Which language are you accessing OpenCV from -- C, C++, Python, Matlab?